# Python Turtle Graphics Aren't Automatically Opening

Tags: python, python-turtle

When I run my code, the python turtle graphics open in a new window but I have to click on that window to view it. Is there any way to make it come up automatically?

Here is my code:

```
ninja = turtle.Turtle()
ninja.speed(1000)

for i in range(180):
    ninja.forward(100)
    ninja.right(30)
    ninja.forward(20)
    ninja.left(60)
    ninja.forward(50)
    ninja.right(30)

    ninja.penup()
    ninja.setposition(0, 0)
    ninja.pendown()

    ninja.right(2)

turtle.Screen().bye()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code snippet below to bring window front.

```
root = turtle.Screen()

rootwindow = root.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()
rootwindow.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
```